# Check which deno "allow" flags are enabled / disabled from within script

Tags: deno

`Deno.args` gives access to all the args (`$@`) after the executed file.

Is it possible to get the flags passed into Deno before that? I am interested in detecting within the script if something like `--allow-run` is true or false and depending on that give a better err message to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`Deno.permissions`](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/runtime/permission_apis) which is currently an unstable API. So the `--unstable` flag is required.

```
const { state } = await Deno.permissions.query({ name: "env" });

if(state !== 'granted')
  console.log(`Can't access env variables`)
```

For checking whether `--allow-run` is on or not you'll have to use:

```
const { state } = await Deno.permissions.query({ name: 'run' });

console.log(state);
```

---

`name` can be one of:

- run
- read
- write
- net
- env
- plugin
- hrtime